Script to merge cells based on cell value
I'm having difficulty finding a way to merge cells based on their values. Here’s what I need:
I have two dependent dropdown menus in columns D and E. When the value "DD9900" is selected in cell E12, I would like a script that merges E12 with E13 and also merges D12 with D13.
To clarify, when the value is DD9900 in E12, the following merges should occur:
-Cell E12 merges with E13
-Cell D12 merges with D13
Example
ChatGPT helped me create a solution for a single cell (E12), but I need a code that applies the same logic to the entire range from E12 to E52.
Can anyone assist me with this?
Thank you!
This is the code which was generated by ChatGPT (only applies to one cell)
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' Check if the changed cell is E12
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("E12")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        ' Clear any previous merges in D12:D13 and E12:E13
        If Me.Range("D12:D13").MergeCells Then Me.Range("D12:D13").Unmerge
        If Me.Range("E12:E13").MergeCells Then Me.Range("E12:E13").Unmerge

        ' Check the value in E12
        If Me.Range("E12").Value = "DD9900" Then
            ' Merge D12:D13 and E12:E13
            Me.Range("D12:D13").Merge
            Me.Range("E12:E13").Merge
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub


As your code also has unmerge commands: Do you want to code to unmerge cells if the cell value in column E is not "DD9900"?

My currently posted code doesn't consider the dropdowns i.e. the 2nd cell becomes empty and loses its dropdown when unmerging. I have since corrected (not posted) this behavior by copying the first cell to the 2nd cell after unmerging. Still, another issue remains: when the changed cell containing DD9900 is above an already merged 'duo' containing DD9900, it will merge and populate correctly but the 3rd cell, the 2nd cell of the previously merged 'duo', now remaining unmerged, also contains DD9900. How should this be handled? Should all three cells merge?

Try the following code.
Target is the cell that was modified. When the cell is not within E12:E52, the routine will exit.
I also simplified the code by checking if only one cell was changed - if not (eg via Cut&Paste), the routine will exit without doing anything.
Now I define two range variables: rColD for the cell to the left of the modified cell (Offset(0, -1), that's column D) plus the next cell below it (Resize(2, 1)). Similar thing for rColE, only that we don't need the Offset-function as we are already in the correct column (column E).
Now we check if the cell got the magic value DD9900.
If yes and the ranges are not already merged, merge them .
If no and the ranges are merged, unmerge them.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const theMagicValue = "DD9900"
    
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, Range("E12:E52")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim rColD As Range, rColE As Range
    Set rColD = Target.Offset(0, -1).Resize(2, 1)
    Set rColE = Target.Resize(2, 1)
    
    If Target.Value = theMagicValue Then
        If Not rColD.MergeCells Then rColD.Merge
        If Not rColE.MergeCells Then rColE.Merge
    Else
        If rColD.MergeCells Then rColD.UnMerge
        If rColE.MergeCells Then rColE.UnMerge
    End If
End Sub


A Worksheet Change: Merge Cells Conditionally
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const TARGET_RANGE_ADDRESS As String = "E12:E52"
    Const TARGET_STRING As String = "DD9900"
    Const OTHER_COLUMN As String = "D"
    Const MERGING_ROWS_COUNT As Long = 2
    Const AFTER_MERGE_ROW_OFFSET  As Long = 1
    Const AFTER_MERGE_COLUMN_OFFSET As Long = 0
    
    ' Restrict the code to a single changed cell.
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Reference the target range.
    Dim trg As Range: Set trg = Me.Range(TARGET_RANGE_ADDRESS)
    
    ' Check if the changed cell ('Target')
    ' is not part of the target range ('trg').
    If Intersect(trg, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Reference the ranges, e.g. for 'E12' - 'E12:E13', 'D12:D13'
    Dim rg1 As Range: Set rg1 = Target.Resize(MERGING_ROWS_COUNT)
    Dim rg2 As Range: Set rg2 = rg1.EntireRow.Columns(OTHER_COLUMN)
    
    ' Implement an error-handling routine to ensure events get enabled
    ' even after an error occurs.
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    ' Disable events to prevent retriggering this code when writing
    ' to this worksheet. Remember to always reeenable them later.
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    ' Unmerge the cells and their merge areas.
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In rg1.Cells
        If cell.MergeCells Then cell.MergeArea.UnMerge
    Next cell
    For Each cell In rg2.Cells
        If cell.MergeCells Then cell.MergeArea.UnMerge
    Next cell
    
    ' Merge the ranges conditionally.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' prevent 'Merge Cells' alert
    If CStr(Target.Value) = TARGET_STRING Then ' A<>a
    'If StrComp(CStr(Target.Value), TARGET_STRING, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ' A=a
        rg1.Merge
        Application.Goto rg1 _
            .Offset(AFTER_MERGE_ROW_OFFSET, AFTER_MERGE_COLUMN_OFFSET)
        rg2.Merge
    End If
    
ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent endless loop if error in continuation
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
ClearError: ' continue error-handling routine
    MsgBox "Run-time error [" & Err.Number & "]:" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub

